# Three.js - generate shape with arcs

Tags: three.js

I am trying to recreate a screw element in Three.js similar to the below picture:

[image]

I have the twisting down using a shape consisting of some points and an ExtrudeGeometry to extrude to the correct length and then twisting the mesh as can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nlooije/pamv8krb/180/).

However, I am confused on what the best way is to generate the correct shape. As can be seen below the shape should consist of circular arcs of different radii extending certain angles from one point to another:

[image]

The centers and radii of these arcs are well defined (not shown in the figure), however I can only seem to use Bezier curves with `Shape` which seem overly complicated for just circular arcs. I can use [`ellipse`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Path.ellipse) with a [`Path`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Path) but converting the `Path` to a `Shape` doesn't seem possible / or is not wel documented.

How do i generate a shape using `Path`/`Shape`/`ShapePath` with circular arcs where i can specify the centers, radii and extending angles and then extrude that shape while twisting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an option of how you can do it with `THREE.Shape()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.absarc(0, -4, 5, THREE.Math.degToRad(60), THREE.Math.degToRad(120));
shape.absarc(0, 4, 5, THREE.Math.degToRad(240), THREE.Math.degToRad(300));

var extrudeGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
  steps: 180,
  depth: 4,
  bevelEnabled: false
});

var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
extrudeGeom.vertices.forEach(v => {
  v.applyAxisAngle(axis, v.z * Math.PI);
});

extrudeGeom.computeFaceNormals();
extrudeGeom.computeVertexNormals();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(extrudeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;

scene.add(mesh);

var profile = new THREE.LineLoop(new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(shape.getPoints()), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "yellow",
  depthTest: false
}));
mesh.add(profile);


render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: thx for the clarification, with your answer i was able to solve the problen

Comment: sideways related: is your way of twisting the mesh better than my way, performance-wise?

Comment: @nluigi it's only about convenience :) For me, it was easier to twist it that way :)